# Can you override Ionic footer height in css for Visual Studio 2015 Cordova project?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using the Ionic framework inside of a Visual Studio 2015 Cordova project.
I would like to override a bar footer that I have inside of a side menu.

I have tried as below...

```
<ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <button class="button button-icon ion-navicon" ng-click="vm.toggleLeft()" ng-hide="$exposeAside.active"></button>
        <h1 style="text-align: left" class="title">My Contents</h1>

    <ion-content class="padding">
        <div data-ng-include="'app/main/main.html'"></div>
    </ion-content>

    <!-- HOW TO OVERRIDE THIS HEIGHT?? -->
    <ion-footer-bar style="height: 20px" align-title="left" class="bar-balanced"></ion-footer-bar>
</ion-side-menu-content>
```

The bar does resize to the 20px via the inline css, however the main **contents** still think the bar is it's original height.

I have seen it mentioned you can set the `$bar-footer-height: 36px;` sccs variable.

I don't seem to be able to find out how to do this when I am in a **Visual Studio** Cordova project. I have seen it mentioned to use the `$ ionic setup sass` to setup the sccs, but I cm still unfamiliar with the sccs, and once again not sure if I can do this when just including the Ionic files inside the Visual Studio Cordova project, i.e. the only links to Ionic are as as below in my index.html

```
<link href="lib/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="lib/js/winstore-jscompat.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

I am not sure how to "link in" the sccs if this is what I need to do.
Is there a way to override this setting just in css, or do I need to "link in" the sccs, and if so how can I do this (once again, in a project setup via Visual Studio 2015 as opposed the the Ionic CL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCSS if one pre-processing format for CSS, you need to convert it to CSS, and include this final CSS to the `index.html`

By running `ionic setup sass`, the build tool `gulp` with tasks are defined. Just run `$ gulp`, and it will generate a CSS file `lib/ionic/ionic.min.css`

So the steps are:

- Modify the `scss/**/*.scss` , anything you want to update.
- Run build command `$ gulp`
- Make sure the final CSS file are included in `index.html`

If you don't know SASS/SCSS, then just don't run `ionic setup sass`, just edit directly `lib/ionic/ionic.css`, add your styles at the bottom of the file, or create a new file, and include it under the line included `ionic.min.css`. It is just a regular web for mobile anyway.

About SASS: http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/sass.html

About Gulp: http://gulpjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for that. I have started looking at the scss, so it looks like that's where I should be doing any modifications, as variables such as $bar-footer-height may be used in more than one style.